# Method loops after return statement

Tags: jsf

I have this JSF backing bean method:

```
public void filterProductsByCategory()
   {
      filtered = true;
      products = controller.obtainProductListByCategory(selectedDesiredCategory);
      showMessage("Filtered by selected category");
   }
```

Which calls the `obtainProductListByCategory` method. This returns a list of `products`. When it is time to refresh the JSF page (it access the getters for the variables it needs), it enters the getter here:

```
 public List<Product> getProducts()
   {
      if(filtered)
      {
          filtered = false;
          return products;
      }
      products = controller.obtainProductList();
      return products;
   }
```

The `obtainProductList` retrieves all the products in the database. My application is a webmarket and what I'm trying to do is to first: get all the products displayed (which is working fine), then: sort by category (there's the problem). For some reason even after the last method enters the `if` statement and returns, it goes back inside, with the variable `filtered` false and proceeds with the method.

I found out through debugging that this code seems to execute everytime too (Located in *Method.java*):

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
           InvocationTargetException
    {
        if (!override) {
            if (!Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(clazz, modifiers)) {
                Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass(1);

                checkAccess(caller, clazz, obj, modifiers);
            }
        }
        MethodAccessor ma = methodAccessor;             // read volatile
        if (ma == null) {
            ma = acquireMethodAccessor();
        }
        return ma.invoke(obj, args);
    }
```

Curious enough, the above loop I mentioned is repeated for as many `products` exist in my List the first time I retrieve all the objects (all the objects in my database). In the end the web page gets all the products back again, even when I tried to filter the results in my `datatable` What is going on here?

Comment: You say the first method calls the second, how so? There is no reference to `getProducts()` in `filterProductsByCategory()`.

Comment: @WilliamGaul Thanks man I posted the wrong piece of code, let me update

Comment: @WilliamGaul Just edited the question, any other thing just tell me, I'll change or add right away.

Comment: clearly something is setting ```filtered = false``` before the getter is called. Things to look out for 1) browser cache or request cache? 2) are you calling twice (once with filter param in request and then once without?).

Comment: I just found the solution to this question thanks to a friend here in StackOverflow. Just post an answer so I can mark it as solved.